# How to install external extensions in GCP's PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, postgresql-extensions

I see [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions?hl=sv) that only allowed extensions can be installed on PostgreSQL in Google Cloud Platform. Is there any possibility to add an extension that is not listed in supported extensions? The extension I need is pg_semver.

Answer (score 3):

There are two options here for your use case:

1. Use a Compute Engine instance as SQL database, rather than
   CloudSQL and you will be able to install any extension you would
   need to.
2. As stated on the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions#requesting-support-for-a-new-extension) you can open a [Feature Request (FR)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187202&template=1162714) to the CloudSQL eng
   team in order to evaluate it and let you know if it will be
   implemented or not in the future.

Bear in mind that feature requests
have not ETA.

Comment: Just submitted one for pgx_ulid: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/290254831